# Django UrlConf NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, forms, url

the following code returns a `NoReverseMatch` only on `browse_years` (the third urlconf). What am I missing? Thanks for your help!

```
url(r'^browse/things/(?P<thing>[\w-]+)/$', 'views.browse.things', name='browse_things'),
url(r'^browse/colors/(?P<color>[\w-]+)/$', 'views.browse.colors', name='browse_colors'),
url(r'^browse/years/(?P<year>\d+)/$', 'views.browse.years', name='browse_years'),

def browse(request):
    thing_list = Thing.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = ThingBrowseForm(request.POST)
        form2 = ColorBrowseForm(request.POST)
        form3 = YearBrowseForm(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            thing = form1.cleaned_data['thing']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('browse_things', kwargs={'thing':thing}))
        elif form2.is_valid():
            color = form2.cleaned_data['color']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('browse_colors', kwargs={'color':color}))
        elif form3.is_valid():
            year = form3.cleaned_data['year']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('browse_years', kwargs={'year':year}))
    else:
        form1 = ThingBrowseForm()
        form2 = ColorBrowseForm()
        form3 = YearBrowseForm()
    return render(request, 'browse.html', {'form1':form1, 'form2':form2, 'form3':form3, 'thing_list':thing_list})
```

---

EDIT: added traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/myproject/views/browse.py" in browse
  18.       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('browse_colors', kwargs={'color':color}))
File "/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  476.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/lib/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  396.                 "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /browse/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'browse_colors' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'color': u''}' not found.
```

---

EDIT: added the forms.py and the template

```
class ThingBrowseForm(forms.Form):
    thing = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Thing.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}))

class ColorBrowseForm(forms.Form):
    color = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLORS_EMPTY, required=False, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}))

class YearBrowseForm(forms.Form):
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEARS_EMPTY, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}))

<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
{{ form1.as_p }}
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
{{ form2.as_p }}
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
{{ form3.as_p }}
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Comment: Could you post your stacktrace and urls.py?

Comment: Sure, added it above. Thanks for any insights @limelights

Comment: You're not getting any colors from your post, thats why it fails. Your URL cant handle empty colors. You should update your question from `browse_years` to `browse_colors` unless you have multiple errors.

Comment: Is there a way to set up the urlconf so that it can handle empty colors? Because the form that is submitted is the `YearBrowseForm`, not the `ColorBrowseForm`, so I dont care that there are empty colors. The form posts should post to `YearBrowseForm`, but the NoReverseMatch occurs on `ColorBrowseForm.` Does that make sense? In other words, both the `ColorBrowseForm` and the `ThingBrowseForm` work properly, but the `YearBrowseForm` returns `NoReverseMatch`.

Comment: Yeah, but you're ending up in the `elif form2.is_valid():` clause. According to your stacktrace anyway.

Comment: I understand that thanks, but not sure how to fix it.... Any ideas that might help? added the forms.py and the template for clarification purposes. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Yeah, break it up, have 1 view for each form. This helps separate it and is less bug prone. If you have a tight coupling with Thing, Year and Color then you should merge them inside a ModelForm of sorts. But if you're keen on keeping your current structure then breaking them into own views are the way to go.

Comment: Sure that makes sense, thanks, but how do I include multiple views in one template? I dont want to have a separate template for each form.. Thanks for any ideas

Comment: You can render the same template for multiple views, templates aren't bound to a view, if that answered your question.