# Django Include Not Including Content

Tags: django, forms, templates, tags, include

I want to use `{% include %}` to include a second form on a page, but the form is empty..

views.py:

```
def year_form(request):
    thing_list = Thing.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = YearBrowseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            year = form.cleaned_data['year']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('browse_years', kwargs={'year':year}))
    else:
        form = YearBrowseForm()
    return render(request, 'browse-year.html', {'form':form, 'thing_list':thing_list})
```

forms.py:

```
class YearBrowseForm(forms.Form):
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEARS_EMPTY, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}))
```

url:

```
url(r'^browse/years/(?P<year>\d+)/$', 'my_app.views.browse.year_form', name='browse_years'),
```

html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% include 'browse-year.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

browse-year.html:

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

This renders an empty form (i.e. the source shows that a form is being included, but it is empty of content). What am I missing here? This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184515/django-urlconf-noreversematch) that I am trying to solve in a different method by using `{% include %}`. Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Does your `base.html` have a `{% block content %}`?

Comment: Thanks @karthikr. Yes my `base.html` has `{% block content %}`. Anything else that I may be missing here? Thanks for your ideas

Comment: if you put the context of `browse-year.html` inline in `browse.html` does it work?

Comment: Hmmm, actually not strangely. The form appeared before when I used all three forms together in the view like in my other question that I linked towards the bottom of my post. I did not change the form or anything else, just tried to set up a different view (shown above) to handle the form because I was having difficulty using all three forms in one view. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: can you pass in the context to `render` method and see ? Also, does the generated HTML have a `<form ` node ?

Comment: Yes, the generated HTML does have a `<form>` node.. However, I'm not quite sure how to pass the context in to `render`, sadly, so if you have a small example I would really appreciate it. Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: [Something like this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/919/)

Comment: Ok. I saved that snippet then imported it as `render_add`. Then I used it in my return statement like `return render_add(request, 'browse.html', {'form':form, 'thing_list':thing_list})`, but I still am getting an empty form. It must be a problem with my view `def year_form(request):` because that is the only thing that I have changed, but I am not sure why it wont work. I really appreciate any helpful ideas! Thanks for sticking with me to help me understand the problem!

Comment: No.. I only meant the `render_to_response` part. Anyway.. it looks like the error is elsewhere.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33099/discussion-between-karthikr-and-nick-b)

Comment: Thanks for the help @karthikr. I am not quite sure why, but re-arranging the order of the forms worked. If I put the form with list of colors after the form with years (shown above), then both work. I have no idea why, but c'est la vie... Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are rendering `browse-year.html`:

```
return render(request, 'browse-year.html', {'form':form, 'thing_list':thing_list})
```

You should be rendering the other html, the one you didn't gave a name, but starts with

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

only by rendering that one you extend the base, and the other content appears.

Comment: Thanks @J. C., I changed to `return render(request, 'browse.html', {'form':form, 'thing_list':thing_list})` (browse.html is my main template) but I still get an empty form. Anything else that I could be missing?